# MATLAB export_fig crops title

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, crop, figure

I am trying to export pdf figures with the export_fig function, but it is cropping away the title. it is doing a nice cropping job at the other axis but not the north one. Anyone had this issue? My code is

```
t = 0:0.01:10;  
s1 = 0.7*sin(6*t) + sin(9*t) + 2*sin(14*t);

plot(t,s1,'LineWidth',0.5)
xlabel('Time[s]')
ylabel('y(t)')
title('This is a title')
set(gca,'FontSize',16);

export_fig( './sinewaves', '-pdf','-transparent')
```

The above code produces this figure [image]

I know I can '-nocrop': `export_fig( './sinewaves', '-pdf','-transparent','-nocrop')` to get the title back, but then it is not cropped on the west and east axis, like below
[image]

Anyone have a solution around this?
Thanks for any comments!

Comment: Have you considered submitting an issue in the project’s issue tracker? https://github.com/altmany/export_fig/issues

Comment: Sounds similar to this fixed issue: https://github.com/altmany/export_fig/issues/239 — Do you have a recent version of the function?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks for comments :) Found a solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by upgrading to MATLAB 2020a and using function:

```
exportgraphics(gcf,'./sinewaves.pdf','ContentType','vector')
```

Comment: it is also now fixed in export_fig.https://github.com/altmany/export_fig, issue #310